# How to pass different id's while using ng-repeat to an ng-click function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

This is my HTML code.In this i am taking multiple values from ng-repeat and for each value i want the respective button to show and hide two div elements.In my web page , the buttons from different member blocks are working to show/hide only the first member block... The button with id=round should toggle btw div elements with id= first and id= second for all members that i get through ng-repeat.

```
 <section id="team">
  <div ng-controller="teamController as tctrl">
   <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-3 bord" ng-repeat="member in tctrl.members">
      <button id="round" ng-click="showHide($index)">
        <img id="direction" src="img/icon/uparrow.png">
      </button>
      <img ng-src="{{member.image}}">
      <div id="first" class="memberabout" >
        <h3 ng-bind="member.title"></h3>
        <h2 ng-bind="member.name"></h2>     
      </div>            
      <div id="second" class="hid" >
        <p ng-bind="member.about"></p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </section>
```

and this is the js function i am trying to use:

```
$scope.showHide = function(index) {
    if (document.getElementById('first') !== undefined) {
     if (document.getElementById('first').style.display == 'none') {
        document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'none';
        var down = document.getElementById('round');
        down.style.top = "201px";
        var direction = document.getElementById('direction');
        direction.src = 'img/icon/uparrow.png';
      } else {
        document.getElementById('first').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('second').style.display = 'block';
        var down = document.getElementById('round');
        down.style.top = "71px";
        var direction = document.getElementById('direction');
        direction.src = 'img/icon/arrowdown.png';
      }
     }
   };
```

How should I pass the id's so that each button works to show/hide the div elements in their block?

Comment: Can you type question clearly and so I can help? Not getting your question properly

Comment: Which part should i explain?

Comment: This part is confusing > But since i am using the id , all the buttons are working to show/hide only the first element.

Comment: Instead of doing `id="first"`, you could do something like, e.g., `id="member-{{index}}"`, so that each element gets a unique ID after the repeat runs.

Comment: okay I will try this.

Comment: Do I have to pass different id for the button as well?

Comment: It is not working.

Comment: Glancing at your code, I would guess yes, but you tell me. If you want to reference a specific element by ID, then you want to make sure its ID is unique from the other elements. That's the point of using an expression inside the repeat. That way you end up with elements with IDs like `member-0`, `member-1`, `member-2`, etc, instead of every button created by the repeat having the same ID. You will have to modify your JavaScript accordingly, after you've generated the unique IDs.

Comment: But i have two div elements, won't they both get the same id this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Angularjs** has many options to cancle using `jQuery` in your applications; options like `modeling`, `directive` and etc...

In your case you didn't need to use id because when we use `ng-repeat` in fact all of items are unique, so we just use them to show/hide or many other option you can do with `object` in the `ng-repeat`.

I hope this sample helps you to figure out how to use it:

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
  var main = this;

  main.members = [{
      image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR4f5PCRqcMgg_KHymC29ABsy-PDFI08mb6qHqMviqbDDHjjuYM9g",
      title: "A",
      name: "jack",
      about: "Hello World"
    },
    {
      image: "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQAxySZHmSrUU1_iIFJHGdDTdmTCAE610QnPwptWGWbMRAbSUzgNA",
      title: "B",
      name: "philip",
      about: "Hello World 2"
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl as tctrl">
  <section id="team">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col" ng-repeat="member in tctrl.members">
          <small>this is unique id if you want to use it: <b>id_{{$index}}</b> </small>
          <div class="card">
          <button ng-click="member.show = !member.show">
                        show/hide
                    </button>
          <img ng-src="{{member.image}}">
          <div ng-hide="member.show">
            <h3 ng-bind="member.title"></h3>
            <h2 ng-bind="member.name"></h2>
          </div>
          <div ng-show="member.show">
            <p ng-bind="member.about"></p>
          </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: you are welcome, please rate answer for other users, thanks

Comment: Is it possible to pass another function to ng-click with this code?

Comment: yes, separate by `;`, but try to create just a main function

Comment: Okay. Thanks a lot.